# Problem with Bootstrap 4 Navbar Dropdown changing other navigation items locations

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my site's navbar. It works fine when I have the navbar expanded, but when it is in a collapsed state (for mobile), the dropdown item in the navbar pushes the other elements to the left and ignores the code (dropdown-menu-right) for making the dropdown align right.

I am not sure why it does this. If anyone can find a solution, it would be much appreciated.

If there is no solution, I would love to hear alternatives as well.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/falconm11/pen/Gemozy?editors=1000)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top border-bottom border-primary" id="main-nav">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Project Name</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row d-sm-flex justify-content-around ml-sm-auto">
      <li class="nav-item btn">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item btn">
        <a href="documentation/current/#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Documentation</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown btn">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-globe"></i> English
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

          <h1 class="dropdown-header">
            <i class="fas fa-language fa-lg"></i> Language
          </h1>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">English</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Other Languages</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the styling of `dropdown-menu`

```
.dropdown-menu{ position:absolute !important;}
```

(Instead of `!important`, I recommend applying the style directly to the `div` to prioritize over Bootstrap's default css)

Comment: The Flex-row is done so that I could have the nav-items shown horizontally instead of the normal vertically. I don't want any of the items to be right aligned. I want the dropdown to display its listed items right aligned, as currently it is coming out left aligned and being clipped of the display area when displayed in mobile view.

Comment: Erm.. have you run my example yet? It keeps the horizontal view instead of vertical and makes the list vertical instead of being clipped in mobile view

Comment: I did run your example, and in the collapsed mobile view, the nav-items are displayed vertical instead of horizontal (In a list that is going down, instead of side to side). This is what I wanted to change by adding the Flex-Row.

Comment: Ah, I got it wrong. I thought you meant the navbar itself and not the one inside. I'll come up with a solution soon

Comment: @GerhardPlesch I've updated the answer. Hope that's what you wanted ^^

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
#dropdown-menu-align-right.dropdown-toggle::after{
  margin:0px !important;  
  vertical-align: initial !important;  
}

.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after{
  position:initial !important;
  display:inline !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;  
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  width: 0px !important;
  min-width: 0rem !important;
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  margin:0ox !important;
  
}

.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:before{
  padding-left: 4px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  position: initial !important;
  display: inline !important;  
  width: 0px !important;
  min-width: 0rem !important;  
}
```